# Best way to pass a list of property names as Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a class `MyDummyClass` to which I'd like to pass some properties in form of a Lambda expression for a later evaluation. So what I can do something like

```
public class MyDummyClass<T>
{
    public MyDummyClass(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

..and then use that class like `new MyDummyClass<Person>(x=>x.Name)`, right?

But then I'd like to pass not only a single property but a list of properties. So I'd write my class like

```
public class MyDummyClass<T>
{
    public MyDummyClass(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> properties)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and I'd **like** to use it like `new MyDummyClass<Person>(new[] { x=>x.Name, x=>x.Surname })` but unfortunately that **doesn't work**! Instead I have to write

```
new MyDummyClass<Person>
     (new Expression<Func<Person, object>>[] { x=>x.Name, x=>x.Surname});
```

But this is a bit awkward to write, isn't it? Of course, using **params** would work, but this is just a sample out of a more complicated piece of code where **using params is not an option**.
Does **anyone have a better option** to come out of this??

Comment: Why don't you want to use `params` ? It's the simplest approach, and it will work without specifying the delegate type.

Comment: I too vote for params. It will keep the syntax very neat and behind the scenes it uses an array which is what you wanted to do in the first place!

Comment: Sure, in this simple example it would, but I took it out of a more complex one where I cannot use params as there are other optional parameters in between which would therefore not work...sadly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
public class MyDummyClass<T>
{
    public MyDummyClass(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        NewArrayExpression array = expression.Body as NewArrayExpression;
        foreach( object obj in ( IEnumerable<object> )( array.Expressions ) )
        {
            Debug.Write( obj.ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would call it like this:

```
MyDummyClass<Person> cls = new MyDummyClass<Person>( item => new[] { item.Name, item.Surname } );
```

The problem is this won't give you the value of the property because no actual Person instance it specified Doing a ToString on "obj" will give you the name of the property. I don't know if this is what you're after, but it maybe a starting point.

Comment: Extracting the property path afterwards is not an issue, I already have that...but thx, your approach could be a possible one.

Comment: I think the main benefit of this approach is that passing the properties into the constructor (2nd snippet) has a simplier, less awkward, syntax and which is close to what you mentioned in your orginal post.

Comment: I have a problem when Person class has properties with different types. For example, it´ll contain a property Age (int). Some help? [Update] using new object[] is right

Comment: This way of passing a list of properties is usually used when specifiying the sort order to the data layer.

Answer (score 8):

Try using *params* instead:

```
public MyDummyClass(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
var dummy = new DummyClass<Person>(x => x.Name, x => x.Surname);
```

Comment: Of course, I know that it would work with params, I cannot use it in my specific situation. 'Cause there are some optional params in between and hence it doesn't work...

Comment: Very sweet.. just what the dr. ordered!!